# Supplements to E. Spanier's Algebraic Topology

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, book-recommendation

What are some sources (books, websites, etc.) that supplement well with Spanier's Algebraic Topology book?  I am currently reading and enjoying it a lot, but I think I do need some supplements, particularly a lengthy explanation and modern terminologies.

I had taken a look at Hatcher, but I did not like it as it is very lengthy to the point of obscuring my understanding..

Comment: The exercises in Hatcher are a good supplement to Spanier. You don't have to read the text necessairly to do the exercises.

Comment: See my answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084636/book-for-algebraic-topology-spanier-vs-tom-dieck?rq=1  for discussion of other possibilities.